# Why JQuery with SetInterval won't work on Firefox?

Tags: html, jquery, firefox, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to learn JQuery running sample codes dealing with SetInterval or Settimeout I find on the Internet, but they won't run or work. For instance, I have the following simple code, but it won't run or even give me error message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function() {
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 333);
$('#here').load(number);
},
1000);
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="here">dynamic content ?</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me what is an error occurred?

Comment: You seem to be missing the jquery import. It's not built-into the browser

Comment: @DipakC There is no error message. I am expecting to see random number beind displayed in place of dynamic content ? every second, but there is no change in the output.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your javascript console in the dev tools?

Comment: Just replace $("#here").load(number) with $('#here').text(number); this line. Your issue will be resolved. And make sure you will add the jquery library in your code.

Comment: @ThN .load() call ajax method

Comment: @DipakC & Slava Knyazev :) It works now... Awesome... Helped me accomplish one of my goal today... Thanks.

Comment: The example you copied was probably loading content from a remote url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first missed to add jquery library and second you should use `.text()` function rather than `.load()` function.

.load() function should use for ajax method.

One of the essential rules that should keep in mind that always put javascript code at the end of the page and before the end of the body tag

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 333);
          $('#here').text(number);
        }, 1000);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="here">dynamic content ?</div>
  </body>
</html>
```